# How do loop through and open *.frm files in VB6?

Tags: vb6, for-loop, file-processing

In VB6, how can I loop through all the `.frm` files in a folder and do something to each of them?

Comment: -1. Stick in the thread you already opened. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208131/pattern-match-processing-of-multiple-frm-files. If you have forgotten something, don't open a similar question again and again, edit your original question and give others a chance to provide you with an answer you are willing to accept.

Comment: And why the heck do you want to do this in VB6, since your original goal seems to be a VB6 to C# conversion?

Comment: @DocBrown: currently looking at VB6 files so I have it open. VB6 is still easier to mash up something quickly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
MyFile = Dir(CurDir() & "\" & "*.frm")
Do While MyFile <> ""
    ' do stuff to file
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: To the downvoter, explain why this answer is not good.  It is actually derived from a Microsoft KB code example so it can't be that bad.  It worked for my purposes.