# Using VB6, how can I check whether a sub-string is at the beginning of a another string?

Tags: vb6, pattern-matching

I need to go through a text file and check whether the start of each line begins with "Attribute".  How should I do this in VB6?

Comment: Again same as two of your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206848/how-to-remove-all-code-from-multiple-vb6-frm-files-and-leave-form-design) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208131/pattern-match-processing-of-multiple-frm-files). If you want to expand on and clarify the question, expand on it, not start a full new question and answer thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim str As String

Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(MyFile)
Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
    str = ts.ReadLine
    If InStr(str, "Attribute") = 1 Then
        ' do stuff
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Regex.  You will have to include the VBScript Regular Expressions library in your references.

```
Dim reg As new Scripting.Regex().
reg.Pattern = "^Attribute"
If reg.Match(line) Then
     ' Do Something
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim sInput As String, check as Boolean
check = true
Open "myfile" For INPUT As #txtFile
While Not EOF(txtFile)
   Input #txtFile, sInput
   If Not Mid(sInput,1,9) = "ATTRIBUTE" Then
       check = false
   End if
   sInput = ""
Wend
Close #txtFile
```

If check = true at the end, all lines start with "ATTRIBUTE", otherwise they do not.

Comment: You need a `UCase()` round `Mid(sInput,1,9)` for this to work

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (code not tested) -

```
Dim ParseDate, AllLinesStartWithAttribute, fso, fs
AllLinesStartWithAttribute = False
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fs = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\yourfile", 1, True)
Do Until fs.AtEndOfStream
    If Left(fs.ReadLine, 9) <> "Attribute" Then
       AllLinesStartWithAttribute = False
       Exit Do
    End If
Loop
fs.Close
Set fs = Nothing
```

Once the code is run if the `AllLinesStartWithAttribute` value is set to true then all lines in your file begin with 'Attribute'. Please note that this code is case sensitive.

Comment: You can use 'Option Compare Text' at start of class/module to make it case insensitive. Then you can use operator Like "Attribute*" - makes code more readable. And you could terminate loop early when you discover that some line is invalid :)

Comment: Posting code that will not compile when 'Option Explcit' is On is not recommended or good practise.

Comment: @Matt - Fair point, code has now been tidied add will compile with `Option Explicit` on.